# Named backreferences in boost::regex

Tags: regex, boost

I am trying to use named back-references in Boost. I tried this, but it is not working. Any ideas what I am missing?

```
boost::regex re("(\d*.\d*\k<name>)")

string_regex_iterator regexItr(
        str.begin(), 
        str.end(), 
        re, 
        boost::match_default | boost::match_partial);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That regex has two *unnamed* capture groups, one nested within the other, and a back-reference ("\k<name>") to a *named* capture group called "name", which doesn't exist.

Also, you're escaping the `\` before the `k`, but not before the `d`.